# Python comment with "#" or "#:"

Tags: python, comments

What is the difference between `#` and `#:` when writing comments in Python?

Comment: The difference between '#' and '#:' is a ':'. What's the question?

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: There is no occurrence of `#:` in the code you linked. What made you think `#:` would be anything special?

Comment: Python only has a # for the comment. Anything after that is commented code. The `:` is part of that comment. As to why someone would include a `:` at the start of their comment, you should ask them.

Comment: @user2357112 Line 294

Comment: They're pretty much the same regarding the implementation, I mean they're just comments, if you replace `#:` with `#a` what's the difference?

Comment: @zephyr: Yeah, I see that now. The link went below all the `#:` comments; there probably should have been another link for those.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flask uses [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) for documentation generation, and [Sphinx uses `#:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) to mark comments that document attributes:

> For module data members and class attributes, documentation can either be put into a comment with special formatting (using a `#:` to start the comment instead of just `#`), or in a docstring *after* the definition.

Additionally, from Flask's [style guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/styleguide/#comments):

> If a comment is used to document an attribute, put a colon after the opening pound sign (`#`)

If you're not using a documentation generator like Sphinx that understands `#:`, there's no point using `#:` comments. Particularly, Python doesn't treat them differently from any other comments.

Comment: Thank you for your patience to a novice. That is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after '#' will be a comment, it's just matter of taste.
You can write in lowercase, uppercase, camelcase, as long as you understand what you're commenting.

If you want to really remark something you could use something like:

```
#####################
###### TITLE ########
#####################
print 'hello world'
```